# How to switch from Mir to Surfaceflinger?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Because of this bug  https://bugs.launchpad.net/mir/+bug/1238695 Ubuntu Touch on the Google Nexus 7 (grouper), Touch randomly freezes, and flickers.

It is bad enough that I cannot do anything except restart the device.

I was just wondering how to workaround this, can I switch back to the "surfaceflinger" that Touch previously used - as this was working nicely on previous versions?

Comment: to anybody that's encountering the "needs to be root" line when you run the above command in adb. break up the line. i ran "adb shell" first, then "adb su" and then" "rm -f /home/phablet/.display-mir && reboot" and it worked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Connect your Nexus to your Ubuntu desktop machine, check if it is connected with

```
adb devices
```

(a line "[device ID] device" should be returned) and then issue the commands

```
adb root
```

(maybe it tells you that you're already 'root') and

```
adb shell rm -f /home/phablet/.display-mir && adb reboot
```

I just did it successfully. Of course, the fallback to Android's surfaceflinger is not a fix but it's a temporary workaround.

---

Alternatively, run

```
adb shell
su
rm -f /home/phablet/.display-mir && reboot
```

Comment: See bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/mir/+bug/1238695.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug with Mir on that device. It has already been reported, but you can workaround the problem by deleting the file `~phablet/.display-mir` on the device, and restarting it. This will switch the display server back to SurfaceFlinger, so the device can be usable until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Where can we find that file at?

Comment: Exactly as specified in the answer. It is under the `phablet` user home directory as `.display-mir`.